# Why is grunt-sass is slower than using sass alone?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-sass

I have used sass alone(not using grunt) and thorough grunt too. What I observe is grunt-sass is lot slower than using sass alone. What could be the possible reasons for this? I have disabled the sourceMap in grunt-sass by following code:

```
compile: {
           options: {
            style: 'nested',
            sourcemap: 'none',
           }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Grunt-contrib-sass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass) is originally based on Ruby and is much slower than [grunt-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass) which is based on [libsass](http://libsass.org/)

Be carefull to choose the libsass version, which shouldn't be slower when used through a gulp/grunt plugin.